# Is it better to put the id attribute in a "a" tag or in the "h1/h2" tag?

Tags: html, tags

I'm learning html in w3 school website and I'm at the "html link" chapter. What I don't understand is why they propose using the id attribute in the link tag instead of the heading tag.

**Their example:**

```
<p> 
<a href="#C4">See also Chapter 4.</a>
</p>

<h2><a id="C4">Chapter 4</a></h2> 
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>
```

**My try:**

```
<p>
<a href="#C4">See also Chapter 4.</a>
</p>

<h2 id="C4">Chapter 4</h2>
<p>This chapter explains ba bla bla</p>
```

Both work the same when I try them but my try take less writing. Is there something wrong in my try that I don't understand.

Comment: There are many, *many* things [wrong with that website](http://w3fools.com/). This is just one of the examples of outdated practice. Use the `h3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before linking to any element by its `id` was possible, you could link to `<a>` elements by their `name`.

The transitional period used `id` and `name` on anchors. There's no need to worry about that unless you are targeting Netscape 4 (I might be misremembering, that could the the first browser to support `id` linking rather than the last to not, but either way, it's ancient history).

W3Schools just has a lot of legacy rubbish in it (and is best avoided as a learning resource).

Use the `id` on the heading (or on the container (`<section>` maybe?) that the heading and associated content is inside).

Comment: Interesting from this perspective that W3Schools have actually selected the worst of both worlds: they've added an unnecessary `<a>` tag, but not given it a `name`, so it's still not actually any more compatible.

Comment: The worst of both worlds is something of a speciality for W3Schools.

Answer (score 4):

It often seems something of a well-kept secret that you can anchor link to elements by their ID, rather than, as more usually, an `a` tag via its `name` attribute. This is probably because the former was a later introduction, and so the `a` tag approach used to be the only means of internal linkage.

So yes, your approach is perfectly valid.

W3SChools, incidentally, while undoubtedly useful at times, has come under fire for some less than solid content over the years. Do not treat it as gospel - it is not affiliated with the W3C, it's just someone's attempt to teach web dev.

Finally, don't confuse head*er* tags with head*ing* tags; in your case it's heading, not header. That's a [different tag entirely](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/).

Comment: Thanks for the heading/header mistake

Answer (score 2):

W3Schools is far from an authoritative resource (see http://www.w3fools.com/ for more on that).

It's perfectly fine to define an `id` on the heading tag, and indeed [the w3 documentation for HTML4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.1)  does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here explain the actual answer very well, but since the original (poor) recommendation came from a W3Schools tutorial, I would like to point you to some more reputable resources:

Firstly, there is [MDN, the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/). Although run by the makers of Firefox, it has a very good coverage of where things are standardised, and how well different browsers support them. It tends to be better for technical reference than tutorials, and I didn't find anything directly relevant, but [the page documenting the `<a>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) includes this note on the `name` attribute:

> Usage note: This attribute is obsolete in HTML5, use global attribute id instead.

I mention MDN mostly because it is a very mature reference site, and a good replacement for that part of W3Schools content.

Secondly, there is [WebPlatform.org](http://www.webplatform.org/) which unlike W3Schools is affiliated with both the W3C and the developers of the major browsers, and aims to include both reference and tutorial information which is accurate and up to date, although some of it is still work in progress.

They have [an HTML link tutorial](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/guides/html_links) which [directly answers your question](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/guides/html_links#Creating_in-page_navigation_with_id_attributes):

> You can also put an id attribute on an `<a>` element, to make it into a page anchor.
>   
> [...]
>   But most browsers you'll want to support these days allow you to write a shortcut for this, and put the ID directly on the element you want to link to
>   
> [...]
>   This is much simpler, so we'd recommend that you stick to this.

Comment: Thanks for the other tutorial reference.